# Why there is a white screen appears for 1sec when starting to run the apps in Android?

Tags: android

When I click the app icons and start to run the apps, it will appear a white screen for 1 sec.
I don't know why.
Is there any idea to clear this white screen and directly go to my activity?

Comment: can you post the onCreate() of the activity that is launched when you start the app?

Comment: Do you perform any tasks, like initializing something or downloading something at the first start?

Comment: yes, but I have set a progressdialog, but it still show the white screen for 1sec, then progressdialog

Comment: Post your `onCreate()` for the first activity.

Answer (score 10):

The [white](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/screen_background_selector_light.xml)/[black](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable/screen_background_selector_dark.xml) screen is the window background image.

The window background is shown while e.g. your `onCreate()` runs and your layouts are being inflated. It can take some time especially if there's a lot of bitmaps that need to be read, decoded and scaled.

Changing the theme works because some themes have a non-default window background. For example, [`Theme.Wallpaper` has a transparent background](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/themes.xml#531). There are other definitions there, too. Essentially what you want is:

```
<style name="YourTheme">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

Programmatically you can achieve the same with

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

at the top of activity `onCreate()`.

(Old question but got bumped up by another answer and there wasn't a good answer.)

Answer (score 4):

Settings. File>Settings>Build,Deployment>Instant Run Deselect all options shown there.

and add below line in your style.xml

```
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
apply changes in AndroidMainfest.xml
 <application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 3):

After I change style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Wallpaper" />

</resources>
```

it works!!
Thanks all

Comment: Answer is unclear since your question does not have a context of your discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in the manifest file of the corresponding activity

```
 android:launchMode="standard"
```

and remove  android:label="@string/app_name" from the corresponding activity ,this actually helped me

Answer (score 0):

In your `manifest.xml` file remove the line `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` for your app. and check it again

Answer (score 0):

Use this tag in your manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Styles add the following things

```
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Hope this will help you and its working for me