# Is making Activity theme translucent correct to avoid white Screen?

Tags: android, android-activity

After a long time search in Google, I found many users saying to make the main `Activity` as translucent to avoid the white screen while opening the application.

Also, I observed that clicking on the app icon in then menu takes time to open the app when translucent is used.

Is this the correct way to avoid the white screen?

Comment: Do you mean a [Splash Screen](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)?

Comment: Setting theme is one option, you can also try setting window background as mentioned in the link ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613217/why-there-is-a-white-screen-appears-for-1sec-when-starting-to-run-the-apps-in-an